# UIButton's title disappears

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I added buttons to xib as normal using iOS 6 SDK and Xcode 4.5.

When I run the app on iOS 6 simulator, there is no problem. But when I run it on the iOS 5.x simulator (or device), the title on the button always disappears(not every time). Lots of my view controllers have this problem.

[image]

**PS: Only Custom type button have this problem**

[image]

**Found the reason:**
    [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:@"取消" forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: post some code what you tried

Comment: How's you set `UIButton` title ?

Comment: How do you set button title via xib or code?please post some line code   you tried..

Comment: Give more details, which describes your problem.

Comment: do you set the title with ´[button setTitle:title forState:state];´ and are your images background images and not set as image (can overlay the title)

Comment: autolayout is already closed

Comment: @bit-whacker most buttons are use xib to create.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "disappears" and "not every time".

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the font title as `Attributed` which is not working with iOS 5 & iOS 5.1 ? change it to `Plain`, now it should work fine with all versions.

**EDIT**

when you select the button in your `xib` your `attribute inspector` should look like this:
[image]

Comment: This will crash  the app not hiding the buttons title on iOS 5 and 5.1 :)

Comment: make sure the font you are using is available for iOS 5 as well

Comment: I am using "System Bold 18.0"~

Comment: do you set the images to the buttons in the xib or in the code?

Comment: @Ushan87 yes, I set the "Background", and leave the "Image" to blank

Comment: check my edit and check whether your values in the attribute inspector matches these values

Comment: @Ushan87 My values are same to yours except the Background color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30406/discussion-between-ushan87-and-yebw)

Comment: @Ushan87 You mean "System Bold 18.0"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting image in `Background` and not in `Image` (see image below)

Also check if you are adding title using code, then `[button setTitle:title forState:state];` should be there.

[image]